# Why isn't GetElementsByTagName working in this form?

Tags: javascript, forms, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyname

I have a form up at avidest.com/new.  The first field is a radio button.  Underneath the email field is a hint that should change depending on which value is selected for the radio button.  If employer is selected, the hint should say "please use your company e-mail address."  If freelancer is selected, the hint should say "please use your school e-mail address.".  For some reason, my javascript code is not working.  I've tried replacing getElementsByTagName with just GetElementsByName but that does not work.  Here is the function that I write in the < head > section of the html page:

```
<script>
function topHint(){
  if(document.getElementsByTagName('Type').value == "Freelancer"){
    document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = "Please use your school e-mail address.";
  }
  if(document.getElementsByTagName('Type').value == "Employer"){
    document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = "Please use your company e-mail address.";
  }
}
</script>
```

I then call the function when the page loads:

```
<body onload = "topHint()">
```

And here is the form elements on the page:

```
<label id="item4_0_label">
    <input type="radio" id="item4_0_radio" data-hint=""  required value="Freelancer" name="Type" />
        <span class="fb-fieldlabel" id="item4_0_span">Freelancer
        </span>
</label>
<label id="item4_1_label">
    <input type="radio" id="item4_1_radio"  required value="Employer" name="Type" />
        <span class="fb-fieldlabel" id="item4_1_span">Employer
        </span>
</label>
<div class="fb-hint" id ="employorlance" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; ">
    Please use your school email address.
</div>
```

Thanks.

After suggestions from stakoverflow, I tried the following but it is still not working:

```
function topHint() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByName("Type");
    for (i in elems) {
        if (elems[i].value == "Freelancer") {
          document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = "Please use your school e-mail address.";
        }

        if (elems[i].value == "Employer") {
          document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = "Please use your company e-mail address.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName('Type') return a collection of values, you need to be more specific, and its the tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName` method doesn't return a single element with the matching name, it returns an array of elements with the matching tag names.

In your case you will get an empty array, because you don't have any `<type>` elements.

---

The `getElementsByName` method also returns an array, and you always get all the radio buttons, not only the selected one, so you have to check the status:

```
function topHint(){
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('Type');
  if(radios[0].checked){
    document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = "Please use your school e-mail address.";
  }
  if(radios[1].checked){
    document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = "Please use your company e-mail address.";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to GetElementsByName but it still is not working.

Comment: @Philip7899: The `getElementsByName` method also returns an array. I added some explanation above.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` selects the HTML tag name (`body, input, form`, etc.)

You want to use `document.getElementsByName("Type")`:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName("Type");

function topHint() {
    for (i in elems) {
        if (elems[i].value == "Freelancer" && elems[i].checked) { ... }
        if (elems[i].value == "Employer" && elems[i].checked) { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's because it returns an array. I updated my answer; try again.

Also, can you clarify what the function is _supposed_ to do?

@Ark What's not going to work? I hadn't provided a code sample.

Comment: I put the code you suggested back into the question above.  It still isnt working.

Comment: @Philip7899

I edited my answer again to make sure the radio is actually checked...

Answer (score 0):

As you already have unique ids on the radio buttons, why not use `document.getElementById`?

```
if(document.getElementById('item4_0_radio').checked){
    // change the hint text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is this:

```
<script>
function topHint(){
  if (document.getElementById('item4_0_radio').checked) {
      document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = 
         "Please use your school e-mail address.";
  }
  else {
      document.getElementById('employorlance').innerHTML = 
         "Please use your company e-mail address.";
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, on each radio button add:  `onclick="topHint();"`

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Rnum/) demonstrating that it works.  You must have something else different in your page.